# SVG <clipPath> fit container and use % unit

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

So I've been trying to make a waving animation for some text in a different color, for that I'm using `<clipPath>` and `-webkit-clip-path`. The `.holder` div contains two elements on top of one another with the same text, one in white, one in grey, and the `clip-path` is applied to the later.

The problem is that I need the `<path>` coordinates to be proportional to the text's size. Here is a [**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1bg8Luxe/).

[image: Graphic explaining my project]

- I've tried setting a `viewBox="0 0 100 100"`, it doesn't work.
- I've also tried using `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` but it doesnt't seem to work in this case, I'm guessing because the text is `display:inline`.

Now if these seems too complicated to analyze, and you understand the basic concept and are willing to do it your way, go for it, I'm *so* open to suggestions at this point.

Also, I'm trying to avoid JavaScript to do this, but if you have to, go ahead, no problem :)

Here is the raw code:

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="back">Text</div>
        <div class="front">Text</div>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <clipPath id="path">
                <path fill="transparent" stroke="black" >
                    <animate 
                        attributeName="d" 
                        attributeType="XML" 
                        values="M 0 50 Q 25 60, 50 50 T 100 50 L 100 100 L 0 100 Z;M 0 50 Q 25 40, 50 50 T 100 50 L 100 100 L 0 100 Z;M 0 50 Q 25 60, 50 50 T 100 50 L 100 100 L 0 100 Z"
                        begin="0s" 
                        dur="1s" 
                        fill="freeze" 
                        repeatCount="indefinite" 
                        direction="alternate" />
                </path>
            </clipPath>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<animate>` element simply alternates between the two paths, to make the "wave" effect.

### CSS

```
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2.5% 5%;
    background:lightcoral;
}
.holder {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    font:6em impact;
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.front {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    color:gray;
    opacity:.3;
    -webkit-clip-path:url(#path);
}
svg {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

This is my css, not nearly perfect, feel free to rip it apart!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have better luck, I believe, if you switch your clipPath to using bounding box units:

```
<clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" ... >
```

Then all your clip path coordinates should be defined in the range 0..1.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath

Comment: [**I love you**](http://jsfiddle.net/2xkyq2Lv/), my problem was when I tried using `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` I didn't know you had to use values from 0 to 1 (I was using 0-100), thank you!

Comment: Is there a tool out there to convert a svg with coordinates that are, for example from 0...500 to 0...1?

Comment: Adam, there is an answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210466/convert-svg-path-data-to-0-1-range?answertab=active#tab-top) with such a script.

Comment: https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/