# Convert SVG path data to 0-1 range to use as clippath with objectBoundingBox

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using a rather complex SVG shape exported from Illustrator as a clipping path.

The problem is that objectBoundingBox requires path data to be within the 0-1 range, and my path contains path data out of this range. Here is what I'm using:

```
<svg>
  <clippath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <path d="M228.6,94.8L176.8, 5.5c-2-3.5-5.8-5.5-9.9-5.5H63.2c-4.1, 0-7.8, 1.9-9.9,5.5L1.5,94.9c-2, 3.5-2,7.8,0, 11.4       l51.8, 89.8c2,3.5, 5.8,5.9,9.9,5.9h103.7c4.1, 0, 7.8-2.4,9.9-6l51.8-89.7C230.7, 102.8,230.7, 98.3,228.6,94.8z M192.8,104.4l-35.5, 
      61.5c-1.4,2.4-4,4.1-6.8, 4.1h-71c-2.8,0-5.4-1.7-6.8-4.1l-35.5-61.4c-1.4-2.4-1.4-5.5,0-7.9l35.5-61.5c1.4-2.4,4-4.1,6.8-4.1h71c2.8, 0, 5.4,1.7,6.8,4.1l35.5, 61.4C194.2,98.9, 194.2, 102, 192.8, 104.4z"/>
  </clippath>
</svg>
```

Is there an easy solution to convert this to the 0-1 range so that I can use objectBoundingBox?

RE: Comment. I am able to apply any number of transforms to the SVG element, but it still doesn't work with objectBoundingBox. For example:

```
<clippath id="clipping" transform="scale(1,1)" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
```

Comment: Wrap it in a transform and you can have any range you like.

Comment: Several variations and that technique doesn't work. Do you have an example where this is successful?

Comment: A scale 1 transform does nothing. You need to scale it down so the range of the path maps to 1 after scaling.

Answer (score 22):

Following the comments from @Robert Longson, just transform the scale of the `<clipPath>`.

The shape I have taken from Figma for this example is 248 x 239, so I just apply the equivalent scale(1/248, 1/239). This gives:

```
transform="scale(0.004032258064516, 0.00418410041841)"
```

This along with `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` means that we can use this shape to clip at any size or aspect ratio.

```css
.clipped {
  clip-path: url(#clip-shape);
}


/* make sure the svg doesn't take up any space in the document */

svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

p {
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Note: SVG width & height have no effect here, but I've left them for reference -->
<svg width="248" height="239">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.0040, 0.0042)">
<path d="M199 30C110 36 2.03409 -46.9894 18 43C29 105 -7.39156 155.325 1.99998 197C18 268 69.8645 202.231 170 237C242 262 288 24 199 30Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>


<img class="clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/80/80" alt="">
<img class="clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
<img class="clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/100/300" alt="">


<p class="clipped">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac est eu risus posuere consectetur vitae sed elit. Quisque mollis, nunc pretium porta eleifend, ligula risus mattis magna, vel tristique lacus massa consectetur mi. Ut sed dui diam. Mauris
  ut mi risus.</p>
```

Comment: Note that `calc()` will not work, you need to precompute the ratio as done here

Comment: Thank you!, this finally helped me understand converting the values to 0-1

Comment: Easiest solution ever! Thanks!

Comment: Based off @ksav answer I thought I should include an example with complex SVG logos. I used a simple aspect ratio of 1000 x 500px.
That equates to: transform="scale(0.001, 0.002)". Keep your sanity by making the image the exact same size as the SVG's.
I made a Codepen here https://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/yLOrejL

Comment: https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/

Comment: How to scale the height responsively? I have my background-size: contatin for the background image but when the image scales below it's min width my clip-path shrinks and its not scaling alongside with the image.

Answer (score 6):

With the following php script, you can transform them:

```
$absolute_path = "M46.9819755,61.8637972 C42.0075109,66.8848566 35.0759468,70 27.4091794,70 C12.2715076,70 0,57.8557238 0,42.875 C0,32.9452436 5.3914988,24.2616832 13.4354963,19.534921 C14.8172134,8.52285244 24.3072531,0 35.8087666,0 C43.9305035,0 51.0492374,4.2498423 55.01819,10.6250065 C58.2376107,8.87215568 61.9363599,7.875 65.8704472,7.875 C78.322403,7.875 88.4167076,17.8646465 88.4167076,30.1875 C88.4167076,32.1602271 88.1580127,34.0731592 87.6723639,35.8948845 L87.6723639,35.8948845 C93.3534903,38.685457 97.2583784,44.4851888 97.2583784,51.1875 C97.2583784,60.6108585 89.5392042,68.25 80.0171204,68.25 C75.4841931,68.25 71.3598367,66.5188366 68.2822969,63.6881381 C65.5613034,65.4654463 62.3012892,66.5 58.7971106,66.5 C54.2246352,66.5 50.0678912,64.7384974 46.9819755,61.8637972 Z";
function regex_callback($matches) {
    static $count = -1;
    $count++;
    $width = 98;
    $height = 70;
    if($count % 2) {
        return $matches[0] / $height;
    } else {
        return $matches[0] / $width;
    }
}

$relative_path = preg_replace_callback('(\d+(\.\d+)?)', 'regex_callback', $absolute_path);
```

Just set the proper width and height variables based on your boundingbox.

This script can be found in the answer of the following question:
[How to apply clipPath to a div with the clipPath position being relative to the div position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495919/how-to-apply-clippath-to-a-div-with-the-clippath-position-being-relative-to-the)

Comment: Awesome! This script DOES WORK! But unfortunately, I ended up losing some points on my SVG file... =(

Comment: OH, MY MISTAKE! I've switched width and height values! Thank you very much guys!!! I don't even know how much time I'd have lost if it wasn't for you. Thank you, thank you, thank you! Maybe we can host this code somewhere else or even translate it to other languages (like JavaScript). =D Just excellent! <3 <3 <3

Comment: More people with the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752027/is-it-possible-to-make-a-svg-clippath-with-a-path-responsive).

Comment: Any idea why my path conversion does not work? It's generated by photoshop and the only apparent difference seems to be the missing spaces between the shapes. The error I see in chrome console: "Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…16,0.00102421875c0.0272633531157…"." https://pastebin.com/raw/7Y7UApp5

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a converter on CodePen as an attempt to solve this problem. It is loosely based on skywlkrs answer, but it supports exponential floats and adds some UI to it:

https://codepen.io/21sieben/full/gQYdEB/

As an example, this will convert

`M11.214377,3.55271368e-15 L64,0 L64,64 L11.214377,64 L1.88513642,41.4772208 C-0.628378807,35.4090582 -0.628378807,28.5909418 1.88513642,22.5227792 L11.214377,3.55271368e-15 Z`

to

`M0.17522,0 L1,0 L1,1 L0.17522,1 L0.02946,0.64808 C-0.00982,0.55327 -0.00982,0.44673 0.02946,0.35192 L0.17522,0 Z`

Notice the exponents in some floats (Sketch likes to export those).

Comment: This does not work for me. The values do not change.