# SVG Path 0 - 1 Range Conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, replace, preg-replace-callback

I found this useful PHP script to make my SVG paths relative to the container, hence responsive when implemented in the front end.

```
$absolute_path = "M0,67.9586133 M0,67.9586133.....Z";
function regex_callback($matches) {
    static $count = -1;
    $count++;
    $width = 1072.01;
    $height = 399.23;
    if($count % 2) {
        return $matches[0] / $height;
    } else {
        return $matches[0] / $width;
    }
}

$relative_path = preg_replace_callback('(\d+(\.\d+)?)', 'regex_callback', $absolute_path);
```

Source: [Convert SVG path data to 0-1 range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210466/convert-svg-path-data-to-0-1-range)

Since currently I'm working with JavaScript and Node, I'm trying to recreate this function using JavaScript. Here is what I got so far, but I'm stuck as the data being returned is exactly the same as the one being input.

```js
function replacer(match, svgWidth, svgHeight) {
  let count = -1;
  count++;
  if (count % 2) {
    return match[0] / svgHeight;
  } else {
    return match[0] / svgWidth;
  }
}

let svgPath = "M0,67.9586133 M0,67.9586133.....Z"
let nuPath = svgPath.replace('(\d+(\.\d+)?)', replacer);
console.log(nuPath);
```

Any help -- direction and/or correction is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use a `<g>` element to keep it responsive?

Comment: I'm using my SVG as a clipPath with `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and to my understanding in order for this to be responsive units need to be 0 - 1. Let me know if I'm incorrect!

Comment: What kind of SVG needs that many significant digits in its coordinates? XD Anyway, you can just set `viewBox` attribute in some cases, have you tried that?

Comment: The PHP code has `$height` and `$width` hard-coded with the values `1072.01` and `399.23`, respectively. The JavaScript code attempts to get the `svgHeight` and `svgWidth` values from the string itself, so their values would be (if it was written correctly) `"67.9586133"` and  `"67.9586133"`. You can't put different values into a function and expect the same result.

Comment: Thanks @JordanRunning -- I'm actually passing the same values as svgHeight and svgWidth in my JS function -- avoided included unnecessary code in the question but I'm realizing it was not clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with a **global** flag:

```
let nuPath = svgPath.replace(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g, replacer);
```

Also, you must define outside the function the width and height:

```
let svgHeight = 399.23;
let svgWidth = 1072.01;
```

And finally you must erase unused function arguments:

```
let count = -1;
function replacer(match) {
  count++;
  if (count % 2) {
    return match / svgHeight;
  } else {
    return match / svgWidth;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response -- very clear, but the output differs from what the Original PHP scripts gives me. For example: by passing `"M0,67.9586133 L53.72258,297.209905...` as the path, the PHP will output: `"M0,0.170224214864 L0.0501138795347...` while the JS will output: `"M0,0.005596962714900048 L0.004664135595750039..`. It looks like a human mistake, but I double checked and can't find the reason.

Comment: I've pulled out `count` variable off the function. By the way, this code converted directly from PHP is dirty.

Comment: Thanks man ! Really appreciate the assistance -- still have the same issue with the output not being the correct one, but I can see progress for the moment because at least I'm getting a different output from the original input.

Comment: What does it output now?

Comment: PHP: `M0,0.170224214864 L0.0501138795347,0.744457843849....` and JS: `M0,0.015028930691581293 L0.004664135595750039,0.005009643563860431`

Here is a CodePen example: https://codepen.io/mmarquez/pen/RgdLWR. Keep in mind I'm using Vue.js so originally makeResponsiveis a method, etc....but you get the idea. If you check the console you will see the difference in output form the PHP code.

Comment: Seems that removing the array[index] of match will return the correct output? Instead of: ` return match[0] / svgWidth ` I just: `return match / svgWidth` and values seems to work! Still Not 100% certain why, but seems to fix the issue :)

Comment: Its now fixed. Match shouldn't have `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!!