# How to scale SVG coordinates in the range 0 and 1?

Tags: html, css, svg, coordinates, scaling

I've been having issues scaling the inline SVG, in order to clip-path it in CSS, in the example to the container of the image that I'm trying to show.

I've seen the other similar questions with solutions but they still don't work as intended:

```
<style>
  .cutR{
        clip-path: url(#cutR)
    }

.blogMainArticleMedia{
  float:left;
  width:100%
}

.image{
  float:left;
  display:block;
  width:100%
}
</style>
<div class="blogMainArticleMedia cutR">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg" alt="image" class="image">
</div>


<svg width="0" height="0" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="cutR" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path d="M0,0c1.45,81.4 320,80 320,80l320,0l320,0c0,0 320,0.62 320,80c0,105.84 0,400 0,400c-1.45,81.4 -320,80 -320,80l-640,0c-171.919,0.239 -319.7,-0.491 -320,80l0,-720Z"
            style="fill:none;" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/thepra/pen/wNdpXW

They suggest to scale the coordinates of the path to a range between 0 and 1, but I can't find any software option(Affinity Designer) or online tool to do such thing.

Did anyone solved this scaling issue?

ps: here's the shape of the path
[image]

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: The path cuts out the image correctly

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly"? Sorry, it is not clear to me.

Comment: I updated the question with what the cut looks like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54090749/5385381

Comment: What are the original dimensions of your SVG?

Comment: 1280x720. Thanks for the reference, it did solve my issue. Should mark it as duplicate or you could answer pointing to the right answer?

Comment: I'll update the answer below with some more details in a minute, but it should provide a working example for your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to the coordinates of the path. Instead, just transform the scale of the `<clipPath>`.

The path you want to use as your clipPath is 1280 x 670, so just apply the equivalent scale (1/1280, 1/670). This gives:

`transform="scale(0.00078125, 0.001492537313433)"`

This along with `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` means that you can use this shape to clip at any size or aspect ratio.

```css
.cutR {
  clip-path: url(#cutR)
}

.blogMainArticleMedia {
  float: left;
  width: 100%
}

.image {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="blogMainArticleMedia cutR">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg" alt="image" class="image">
</div>

<!-- Viewbox has no effect -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 1280 670">
  <defs>
    <clipPath transform="scale(0.00078125, 0.001492537313433)" id="cutR" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
       <path d="M0 0C1.45 75.8834 320 74.5783 320 74.5783H960C960 74.5783 1280 75.1563 1280 149.157V522.048C1278.55 597.932 960 596.627 960 596.627H320C148.081 596.849 0.3 596.169 0 671.205V0Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/vbmReR)

Comment: This is gold! Worked like a charm. Thank you!