# CSS SVG ClipPath - Fit path to height

Tags: html, css, svg

### The task

I'm trying to have an image which is the full height of the screen, and clipped with an SVG mask, which is also full height.

### The problem

Although the image is full height, the SVG clipping is always the same size and will not resize to the full height of the image.

I've read about using: `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`
on the clipPath, but this seems to break it further.

CSS:

```
img {
      position: absolute;
      clip-path: url(#path); 
      -webkit-clip-path: url(#path); 
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 200 440">
        <defs>
            <clipPath  id="path">
                <path d="m54.3,1c64,1 89.3,85 89.8,85.6c1,0.4 7,37 19,53.7c11.8,16.6 30.7,28.5 35,33.8c4.3,6 9,8 4.8,17s-18.8,7 -24.8,20c-6,13.7 7.5,11 8.6,22c1,11 -31.2,14 -29.6,27c1.4,13 22.4,12 24,23c1.5,11.6 -9,10 -13,18c-3.8,8 15.6,20 5,38c-11,18.5 -57.7,7 -84,32.5c-26.4,25.3 -35.5,70 -34.4,70.4c1,0.4 -64,3 -61.8,-1c2.1,-4 -4.9,-440 2.1,-440s-4.6,-1 59.4,0l-0.1,0z"/>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>

    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/20100726_Kalamitsi_Beach_Ionian_Sea_Lefkada_island_Greece.jpg">

    </svg>
</div>
```

jsFiddle showing problem - https://jsfiddle.net/kjnovege/1/

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: It might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788082/svg-clippath-fit-container-and-use-unit